# Как отображать приложение при выбросе ошибки?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Имеется корневой компонент

```
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary'

export const App = () => {
    return    
    <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorUI}>  //ErrorUI монтируется в error-root
      <someApp/>
    </ErrorBoundary>

}
```

в одном из дочерних компонентов я выбрасываю ошибку а-ля

```
    useEffect(() => {
        throw new Error('Destroy everything!')
    }, [])
```

при запуске приложения у меня соответственно выбрасывается ошибка, есть компонент в error-root, а в корневом root пусто, я бы хотел выводить ошибку в виде всплывающего тултипа и чтобы основное приложение все равно рендерилось, но не могу понять как сделать, подскажите - что нужно изменить

Comment: Проще обработчики ошибок расставлять в потенциально опасном коде. Если у вас падает компонент, то он отрисован не будет. `ErrorBoundary` поможет перехватить ошибку и поставить" дефолное значение. Всякие всплывающие окна, скорее всего, придется рисовать самостоятельно.  Что бы ваш компонент был поставлен в DOM гарантированно, вам надо не допускать высплытия ошибки за пределы внутренних функций. Старый добрый try catch(и .catch() для промисов) и проверка переменных помогут вам в этом.